# ERROR: 1935 when installing an assembly to WinSxS

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2013, installation, installshield, winsxs

I have a Win32 assembly which I've been deploying though the installer into WinSxS. Everything worked fine till recently when I upgraded my projects to VS2013. Since upgrading, I've noticed that the installer is throwing up an error and rolling back the installation. On verification, I realized that the the problem was indeed with the installation of the Win32 assembly into WinSxS. On further exploration, it turned that the problem was only caused when the assembly was built in Release configuration but not in Debug configuration. I've verified the Linker and Manifest Tool properties in both configurations and there are no differences. I wonder what could cause such a problem?

The installer log says:

> Error 1935. An error occurred during the installation of assembly component {65E42E52-10F8-482D-B246-0599A4B162B5}. HRESULT: 0x800736FD. assembly interface: IAssemblyCacheItem, function: Commit, assembly name: MyAssembly,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="75c921dc6145ab19",type="win32",version="3.0.0.0"
>   === Logging stopped: 7/31/2014  11:28:05 ===

Comment: Look at both of your MSIs (debug and release) in Orca and compare MsiAssembly and MSIAssemblyName tables too see if there is any difference. Do you build installers with Wix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was eventually able to figure out the problem with the installation. It appears to be an issue with `makecat.exe` delivered with VS2013. Once I went back to using the same executable from the VS2010 directory, everything started working fine.